# CSS - Fonts are not rendering correctly in firefox for offline data

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/download-course-materials/ try downloading the course from this link.

from the zip folder when i view the pages offline in firefox the fonts are not rendered correctly you can compare it with chrome and IE by opening the course in offline mode in both the browsers.

I tried using local() in @font-face src: but there was no impact, cant use .htaccess option as the course will be available offline after downloading and it may not be necessary to have apache on machines.

I tried changing the fileURI in about:config of firefox it worked but it is not a perfect solution as there are many users and they can't do this.
Please Suggest some solution.

**code for base.css:**

```
     @font-face {
 font-family: TitilliumText22LLight;
     src: local("TitilliumText22LLight"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002- webfont.eot');
     src: local("TitilliumText22LLight"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
 url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.otf') format("otf"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.woff') format("woff"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.svg#TitilliumText22LLight') format("svg");
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     }


     @font-face {
 font-family: TitilliumText22LRegular;      /* Titillium Regular */
     src: local("TitilliumText22LRegular"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L003-webfont.eot');
     src: local("TitilliumText22LRegular"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L003-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
 url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L002-webfont.otf') format("otf"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L003-webfont.woff') format("woff"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L003-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L003-webfont.svg#TitilliumText22LRegular') format("svg");
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     }

     @font-face {
 font-family: TitilliumText22LBold;     /* Titillium Bold */
     src: local("TitilliumText22LBold"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.eot');
     src: local("TitilliumText22LBold"), url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"),
 url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.otf') format("otf"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.woff') format("woff"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"),
     url('../webfonts/TitilliumText22L005-webfont.svg#TitilliumText22LBold') format("svg");
     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: normal;
     }`
```

**code for Courses_new.css :**

```
    #course_nav li a,
    #course_nav li a:visited {
font-family: TitilliumText22LBold, Verdana;
color: #666;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: inherit;
padding: inherit;
width: 125px;
    }
```

in the above scenario course_new.css is calling the class TitilliumText22LBold from base.css  but it is not applying on the text in offline mode which  you can see in the left navigation panel when opening the page from zips.

When i remove verdana it is applying TitilliumText22LBold but still the fonts are not same as  fonts in online mode.

Please suggest what should be done next so that this font should be applied in offline mode as well.

Comment: Firstly, questions on Stack Overflow should be useful for the community as a whole, no a single person. Could you please try to localise the problem you're having so that your question has more value. Secondly, it's far better to paste your code, rather than pasting links to remote sites, and asking people to download zips

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom fonts myself. My code worked on both sides, on and offline.
This is the CSS rule i added in the first lines of my css file:

```
@font-face { font-family: BebasNeue; src: url('../fonts/BebasNeue.otf'); }
```

And then i just called them in my css like this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: BebasNeue;
}
```

I hope this is of any help.

**And, my advise to you is to use .otf files! I have learned that TTF files won't load locally. that also might be your problem :)**

Comment: Thanx but i tried using .otf files as suggested by you it didn't make much difference. However, i tried removing verdana fro courses_new.css  worked for me but yet the fonts are not desired as the TitilliumText22LBold class is not applying to navigation pane can you suggest something else.

Comment: Have you already tried using a similar looking google font?  Because there is a font named Tittilium Web. That should help you! 
This for the HTML
`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

and this in the css
`font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;`